# Ajax call in a diffrent .js file

Tags: ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I want to make an Ajax call from different .js file. I did something like this:

```
function ajax(url,success,error)
{
    success+="(data)";
    error+="(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)";

    console.log("Starting AJAX");
    console.log("Success function: " + success);
    console.log("Success function: " + error);

    $.ajax({                                                                   
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: url, 
        callback: 'jsonpCallback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        jsonp: '_jsonp',
        scriptCharset: "utf-8",
        contentType:  'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp json',
        timeout : 5000,

        success: success_contact(data),
        error: error_contact(),
    });
}
```

There are also functions  success_contact and error contact. I started it like this:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    ajax('http://topfirma-dev/topfirma-www/services/rest/contact/list','success_contact','error_contact');
});
```

Ajax call is called, but there is an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

And here is my question. How can I catch data from my Ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `success_contact` and `error_contact` are defined elsewhere, you do not need to call them as functions there, you just tell which functions they are.

```
var success_contact = function (data) {
    /* do something */
}

var error_contact = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    /* do something */
}

// ...

$.ajax({                                                                   
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: url, 
    callback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonp: '_jsonp',
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType:  'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp json',
    timeout : 5000,

    success: success_contact,
    error: error_contact,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be passing the name of the function to the success (and error) properties when you make your ajax call (or pass the function inline).

e.g.

```
$.ajax({                                                                   
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: url, 
    callback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonp: '_jsonp',
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType:  'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp json',
    timeout : 5000,

    success: success_contact,
    error: error_contact,
});
```

Then you should declare the success_contact (and error_contact) functions:

```
var success_contact = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```

or:

```
$.ajax({                                                                   
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: url, 
    callback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonp: '_jsonp',
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType:  'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp json',
    timeout : 5000,

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    // Do stuff
},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Do stuff
}
});
```